# Show that $\mathfrak n_- \simeq \mathfrak n_+^{\ast}$ and $\mathfrak h \simeq \mathfrak {h}^{\ast}.$

Tags: lie-algebras, bilinear-form, semisimple-lie-algebras, cartan-geometry

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a simple Lie algebra with the triangular decomposition $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak n_+ \oplus \mathfrak n_- \oplus \mathfrak h,$ where $\mathfrak h$ is the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak n_+$ and $\mathfrak n_-$ are the direct sum of root subspaces of $\mathfrak g$ corresponding to the positive and negative roots respectively. Let $(\cdot, \cdot)$ be a non-degenerate invariant bilinear form on $\mathfrak g$ (e.g. the killing form). Then show that it induces isomorphisms $\mathfrak {n}_- \simeq {\mathfrak {n}_+}^{\ast}$ and $\mathfrak h \simeq \mathfrak h^{\ast}.$

Could anyone please help me in this regard? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have asked a lot of questions lately, both here and on MO. It might be a good idea to try to solve some of these yourself first. What have you tried?

Comment: @Callum$:$ I have answered many of them myself where nobody could answer which you can see. It's not your duty to check how many questions did I ask in MSE. BTW if you have any idea on how to approach the problem please give me some hint at least. I am yet to get this thing.

Comment: This is not criticism or judgement, just advice. Forcing yourself to find the answer helps you understand it and the surrounding ideas better. In this particular case you may find these (and the ideas needed) in a Lie algebras textbook like Humphreys. Hint for the first: consider what the Killing form looks like on two root spaces.

Comment: @Callum$:$ Then $\mathfrak {g} = \mathfrak h \oplus \mathfrak g_{\alpha} \oplus \mathfrak g_{- \alpha}.$ How do we show that $\mathfrak g_{-\alpha} \simeq \mathfrak g_{\alpha}^{\ast}\ $? For this I need to have a non-degenerate pairing between these two. Suppose for some $x \in \mathfrak g_{\alpha}$ we have $K(x,y) = 0$ for all $y \in \mathfrak g_{-\alpha}$ then how to show that $x = 0\ $?

Comment: Recall that the Killing form is given by $(x,y)=\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{ad}(x) \circ \mathrm{ad}(y) $. It is a basic fact of Lie algebras (you can find it in Humphreys) that for $0\neq x \in\frak{g}_\alpha$, $\mathrm{ad}(x)(\frak{g}_\beta) = \frak{g}_{\beta+\alpha}$ (note equals, not just subset) and that this is non-zero if $\beta+\alpha$ is a root. Using this you should be able to see $(x,y)\neq 0$ if they are non-zero and lie in opposite root spaces. Conversely if $y$ is in any other root space or in the Cartan subalgebra it must be 0, again just using the definition of the Killing form.

Comment: @Callum$:$ Get it for the case when $\mathfrak {g}$ has two roots. Just solved it myself. If you want I can give detailed answer. But how to extend it for finitely many roots? In this case indeed we have a pairing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142717/discussion-between-callum-and-anil-bagchi).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\Phi$ be the root system and for $\alpha \in \Phi \cup \{0\}$ let $\mathfrak g_\alpha$ be the subspace of $\mathfrak g$ where all $h \in \mathfrak h$ act via $\alpha(h)$ (note $\mathfrak g_0 = \mathfrak h$).

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \Phi \cup \{0\}$, then for all $x \in \mathfrak g_\alpha, y \in \mathfrak g_\beta$, by invariance of the form we have

$$-\alpha(h) \cdot (x,y) = ([x,h],y) = (x,[h,y]) = \beta(h) \cdot (x,y)$$

for all $h \in \mathfrak h$ which entails

$$ \alpha \neq -\beta \implies \mathfrak g_\alpha \perp \mathfrak g_\beta.$$

But the form is non-degenerate. Can you see from here that the restriction of the form to each $\mathfrak g_\alpha \times \mathfrak g_{-\alpha}$ is non-degenerate, and how that implies what you want?